# vite + vue TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkedNumbers')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

My template

```js
<script setup>
import { computed, ref, watch } from "vue";
let checkedNumbers = ref([]);



function sum(){
  return this.checkedNumbers.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a)+ parseFloat(b);
  },0);
}
```

```html
<span id="prixSum" class="sm:text-center lg:text-left block font-bold text-sky-500 text-xl font-semibold lg:text-left">
        {{ prixSum = sum()== 0 ? model.prixS1 : parseFloat(sum()+ model.prixS1).toFixed(2) }}

</span>
<ul>
  <li>
<span  class="px-5 py-3 font-semibold text-sm tracking-wider bg-blue-500  text-center rounded dark:bg-indigo-700  dark:text-gray-900">{{model.prixS1}} </span>

<input type="checkbox" id="model.prixS2" name="model.prixS2" v-model="checkedNumbers"
       :value="model.prixS2"  class="hidden peer" required>


<input type="checkbox" id="model.prixS3" name="model.prixS3" v-model="checkedNumbers"
       :value="model.prixS3"  class="hidden peer" required>

  </li>
</ul>
```

{{ prixSum = sum()== 0 ? model.prixS1 : parseFloat(sum()+ model.prixS1).toFixed(2) }}

{{model.prixS1}}

- 

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using script setup, `this` is undefined, just use variables.

```js
<script setup>
import { computed, ref, watch } from "vue";

// smth like `{ value: [] }`
let checkedNumbers = ref([]);

function sum(){
  return checkedNumbers.value.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a)+ parseFloat(b);
  },0);
}
```

Comment: thanks you saved  ....can i have document for script setup vue 3

Comment: @FipoGito https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html